# Datatables and retrieve a value of input field from footer

Tags: javascript, datatables

I've a problem with Datatables and probably cached variables.
I need to retrieve, on submit, `#peso_totale_componenti` to check it's validity.

Correct value in example is `15.4` like it's input value.

I've inserted an alert to check this input but I get `6.6` (which is value of the first row.)

```
  var peso_totale_componenti = $("#peso_totale_componenti").val();
  alert(peso_totale_componenti);
```

I don't know why. But if I change tab-panel or resize window and i click the submit, this time the value in alert is correct `(15.4)`.

It seems to be a problem with cache value of datatables?

UPDATE: ID is unique. I get the sum with a drawcallback in Datatables:

```
drawCallback: function () {
      var api = this.api();
      var index = 3; //colonna pesi
      $( api.column(index).footer() ).html( "<input type='hidden' id='peso_totale_componenti' value='" + api.column(index).data().sum() + "'>" + api.column(index).data().sum() ); //peso totale
    },
```

UPDATE 2: Solved using:

```
    table.rows().invalidate('dom').draw(false);
```

after every insert/remove of row.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is because you've used the same ID value twice. ID's should be unique to **one** element.

Use classes to target multiple elements that need the same styles/js applied then use ID's to target specific elements.

Comment: No, i haven't used it twice. it only appear one time: in the footer of table

Comment: What is the ID of the element in the first row with a value of 6.6?

Comment: No IDs. I use api.sum() to get sum on every drawcallback. I've update the post

Comment: @GiuseppeLodiRizzini Please answer: What is the ID of the element in the first row with a value of 6.6?

Comment: Solved with: table.rows().invalidate('dom').draw(false); atfer every row insert/delete

Answer (score 0):

You can try to increase the specificity number of the selector by using the following selector;

```
var peso_totale_componenti = $("table tfoot tr th input#peso_totale_componenti").val();
alert(peso_totale_componenti);
```

Other elements may have the same id in the dom

Comment: Can you add a class to the input and use it with the selector I specified above like this;  "table tfoot tr th input.newClass"